# Fractional Laplacian when n < 2s

Tags: fractional-calculus

Let $(-\Delta)^s $ be the fractional laplacian. Consider the space dimension to be $n = 1$, so that

$$
(-\Delta)^s u = C_{1,2s}p.v.\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|y-x|^{1+2s}}dy
$$

Do you know some literature about the case $n < 2s$, namely $n = 1$ and $s\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$? I want to know the properties of this operator for that range of values since most people focus on the case $n > 2s$ due to the Riesz kernel's existence (I guess). Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

There is literature on the case $n =1$. For example, if $n=1$, $\frac 1 2 <s<1$ then the fundamental solution is still given by the Reisz potential. If $n=1$ and $s= \frac 1 2 $ then the fundamental solution is $- \frac 1 \pi \log \vert x \vert$.

For further reading see *Fractional Thoughts* by Nicola Garofola, in particular, Theorem 8.4 and Remark 8.7. In Remark 8.7 he also references another paper which may be of use to you, but I haven't read this paper myself, so I can't confirm that.